# concatenate const strings and variable inputs in C

Tags: c, string, parameters, concatenation

I'm working in C and I have to concatenate a few things.

Right now I have this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char tftp_cmd[TFTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];    
    char ip_server[IP_MAX_LEN];
    char file_name[FILE_MAX_LEN];
    const char * tftp_get = "tftp -g -r ";

    strcpy(&ip_server[0], argv[1]);
    strcpy(&file_name[0], argv[2]);

    tftp_cmd[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(tftp_cmd, tftp_get);
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);
    strncat(tftp_cmd, file_name, sizeof(tftp_get) + sizeof(file_name));
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);     
    strncat(tftp_cmd, ip_server, sizeof(tftp_get) + sizeof(file_name) + 1);
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);
    return 0
}
```

This app returns :

```
# ./test_app 10.0.0.1 MY_TEST_FILE_17.12.2015
tftp get command = tftp -g -r 
tftp get command = tftp -g -r MY_TEST_FILE_17.12.2015
tftp get command = tftp -g -r MY_TEST_FILE_17.12.201510.0.0.1
```

I would like `tftp -g -r MY_TEST_FILE_17.12.2015 10.0.0.1`

I am using the good way ?

Comment: just use `sprintf`...

Comment: Something like `&ip_server[0]` obfuscates your intention here. As you want to use the array, better use the name of the array: `ip_server`. While technically identical, it makes your intention not only to use the first entry more clear (and is less to type & read)..

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `strcpy(&ip_server[0], argv[1]);`, never access any entry in argv[] beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user.  When incorrect number of parameters, then output a 'usage' statement to show the use the format/syntax of a correct command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently, there are various problems with the code presented:

- The arguments are unnecessarily copied into temporary buffers, with no check for buffer overflow. (eg. `strcpy(&ip_server[0], argv[1]);`)
- The third argument to `strncat` is the maximum size of the second argument, not of the concatenated string. The value provided in the example code allows for buffer overflow.
- The desired space character is not inserted before the ip number.
- There is an over-reliance on fixed-sized arrays.

More importantly, the general approach is both hard to read and inefficient. String handling in C is a bit annoying, but there have been significant improvements in the C string library since 1989, and using new library features can make your code safer, more readable, and even more efficient. Good C code should make optimal use of library features available.

(The repeated use of `strncat` in the original code is inefficient because `strncat` will rescan the output string from the beginning on each invocation, leading to a quadratic execution time as the string gets longer.)

A much better approach is to use `snprintf` to provide a simple, legible, safe and efficient formatting operation:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc < 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Too few arguments.\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  /* These are for documentation; no copying is involved */
  const char* file_name = argv[2];
  const char* ip_server = argv[1];
  char tftp_cmd[TFTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
  int outlen = snprintf(tftp_cmd, sizeof tftp_cmd,
      "tftp -g -r %s %s", file_name, ip_server);
  if (outlen >= sizeof tftp_cmd) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Arguments are too long\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  printf("%s\n", tftp_cmd);
  return 0;
```

}

This could be improved by allocating memory instead of using fixed-size buffers:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc < 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Too few arguments.\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  char* tftp_cmd = NULL;
  const char* file_name = argv[2];
  const char* ip_server = argv[1];
  int outlen = snprintf(tftp_cmd, 0,
      "tftp -g -r %s %s", file_name, ip_server);
  tftp_cmd = malloc(outlen + 1);
  snprintf(tftp_cmd, outlen + 1,
      "tftp -g -r %s %s", file_name, ip_server);
  printf("%s\n", tftp_cmd);
  free(tftp_cmd);
  return 0;
```

}

Some modern C libraries implement `asprintf`, which does the memory allocation automatically, and is even more convenient since it avoids calling `snprintf` twice.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc < 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Too few arguments.\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  char* tftp_cmd = NULL;
  const char* file_name = argv[2];
  const char* ip_server = argv[1];
  if (0 > asprintf(&tftp_cmd, 
                  "tftp -g -r %s %s", file_name, ip_server)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  printf("%s\n", tftp_cmd);
  free(tftp_cmd);
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thank for these examples. The last one seems quite efficient ! Just a question (maybe stupid), but in your second sample code, why the second parameter given as parameter to snprintf() is equal to `outlen + 1`. The interrogation focuses on the 1

Comment: @SnP: Read the documentation for `snprintf`. The length you provide as the second argument is the size of the buffer, which must have room for the terminating NUL. The length it returns is the number of characters in the output, not including the terminating NUL.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that `&ip_server[0]` is essentially the same as `ip_server`, second `sizeof` does not do what you apparently think it does.

Here

```
strncat(tftp_cmd, file_name, sizeof(tftp_get) + sizeof(file_name));
```

Instead, do something like

```
strcat(tftp_cmd, file_name);
```

`tftp_cmd` has to point to a large enough memory buffer.

Using `strncat()` could be very dangerous, because it could leave out the terminating `'\0'`.

You also don't need to initialize the `tftp_cmd` when it's the first parameter to `strcpy()`, but you need it to point to a large enough memory buffer. And you don't need to copy `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` at all, you can use them directly. If you must, you can use a pointer instead of copying memory which is expensive.

Finally, as suggested by @[EugeneSh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh) in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336736/concatenate-const-strings-and-variable-inputs-in-c/34336783#comment56414821_34336736), the best way is `snprintf()`, this is an example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *tftp_cmd;
    ssize_t length;
    const char *format;

    format = "tftp -g -r %s %s";
    if (argc < 3) // Check that parameters were passed to the funcion
        return -1;
    length = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, argv[2], argv[1]);
    tftp_cmd = malloc(length + 1);
    if (tftp_cmd == NULL)
        return -1; // Allocation Error
    sprintf(tftp_cmd, format, argv[2], argv[1]);
    // Use the `tftp_cmd' here, for example
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", tftp_cmd);
    // And then, free it
    free(tftp_cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank for all these reliable tips. I learned a lot thru this post and the solution works exactly how I expect ! Just a question, why the input buffer is specified NULL as first snprintf() parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

the following code corrects the problems found in the posted code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char tftp_cmd[TFTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char ip_server[IP_MAX_LEN];
    char file_name[FILE_MAX_LEN];
    const char * tftp_get = "tftp -g -r ";

    if( 3 != argc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <serverIP> <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line parameters

    strcpy(ip_server, argv[1]);
    strcpy(file_name, argv[2]);

   // tftp_cmd[0] = '\0'; -- not needed because first data is set by strcpy()
    strcpy(tftp_cmd, tftp_get);
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);
    strcat(tftp_cmd, file_name);
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);
    strcat(tftp_cmd, ip_server );
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);
    return 0
}
```

however, that series of calls to `strcat()` could (possibly) overflow the `tftp_cmd[]` buffer. and the posted code is trying to use `strncat()` so the following is safer as it will not overflow the tftp_cmd[] buffer.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char tftp_cmd[TFTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char ip_server[IP_MAX_LEN];
    char file_name[FILE_MAX_LEN];
    const char * tftp_get = "tftp -g -r ";

    if( 3 != argc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <serverIP> <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line parameters

    strcpy(ip_server, argv[1]);
    strcpy(file_name, argv[2]);

   // tftp_cmd[0] = '\0'; -- not needed because first data is set by strcpy()
    strncpy(tftp_cmd, tftp_get, TFTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);

    strncat(tftp_cmd, file_name. TFTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - strlen( tftp_cmd ) );
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);

    strncat(tftp_cmd, ip_server,  TFTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - strlen( tftp_cmd );
    printf("tftp get command = %s\n", tftp_cmd);
    return 0
}
```

however, this does not provide any indication that the buffer actually contains the whole data string.

so something like the following could be inserted before the `return` statement

```
    if( (strlen( tftp_get) + strlen( file_name ) + strlen( ip_server ) +1 ) > TFTP_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE )
    {
        printf( "unable to create the full contents of the tftp command\n" );
    }
```